# Как оптимизировать mysql бд для уменьшения использования ОЗУ

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, highload, big-data

В проекте используется бд mysql 8, которая лежит в контейнере docker. Столкнулся с трудностью нехватки ОЗУ при размере бд 6гб и примерно 2,5 млн записей. Ождается что будет больше и со временем будет понемножку возрастать, записей планируется около 5млн.

Конфиг бд `my.cnf`

```
    [client]
port                        = 3306
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice                        = 0

[mysqld]
user                        = mysql
#secure-file-priv            = NULL
pid-file                    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                        = 3306
basedir                     = /usr
datadir                     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                      = /tmp
secure-file-priv            = NULL

skip-external-locking

max_allowed_packet          = 100M
key_buffer_size             = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 6000M
innodb_file_per_table       = 1
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
max_connections             = 160

long_query_time             = 1

expire_logs_days            = 1
max_binlog_size             = 100M
disable_log_bin

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet          = 16M
```

`docker-compose.yml` только по mysql, могу выложить по остальным контейнерам если нужно.

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.20
    container_name: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd"
      - "MYSQL_USER=app"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=app"
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

Структура самой объемной таблицы `http://prntscr.com/stkj5d` `http://prntscr.com/stkr3r` (скриншоты)
Диск ssd среднего качества, примерно 500 мбит чтение и 250-300 запись.

Сейчас ОЗУ заполняется под завязку 6500 мб, постоянно висит не освобождается и начинает уменьшаться скорость выборки. Подскажите где могут быть ошибки и в какую сторону копать? По сути все лоты не должны висеть в памяти, там 90% завершенных лотов которые никого не интересуют, они для количества ну или кто-то захочет их поднять посмотреть, а остальные 10% реальные рабочие данные, работа с которыми должна быть максимально быстрой.

Comment: у вас система случайно не начинает "свопить"? При свопе все сильно замедляется. Если свопит, то надо уменьшить `innodb_buffer_pool_size` и попробовать снова

Comment: Своп используется, проект пока на локальной машине, тем более под виндовс, пока тестируем и не можем определиться какое железо нам нужно. Я честно говоря думал mysql сервер будет менее прожорлив к ОЗУ...

Comment: MySQL использует столько памяти, сколько вы сконфигурировали в `my.cnf`. Еще есть несколько параметров, которые конфигурируют сколько памяти будет использовать каждое БД соединение - если у вас очень много соединений с БД, то стоит проверить и эти параметры тоже

Comment: А можно как-то держать "на виду" те 10% лотов, чтобы выборка по ним занимала меньше времени ?

Comment: "MySQL использует столько памяти, сколько вы сконфигурировали в my.cnf" Если я ставлю менее 4гб то скорость выборки начинает уменьшаться. Вот я потому и написал, что на таком не большом количестве столько ОЗУ жрет. Конечно в лотах текстовые поля могут занимать десятки мегабай места, может это как-то тоже влияет.

Comment: Тут много факторов - очень многое зависит от характера нагрузки (много ли пользователей БД будут параллельно выполнять запросы); какие запросы будут выполняться наиболее часто - их нужно оптимизировать в первую очередь; какие индексы существуют? используются ли они? правильно ли они используются? может быть нужны доп. индексы; после того как вы настроили и проверили индексы можно приступить к [тонкой настройке сервера MySQL](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/)

Comment: также стоит понимать сколько памяти занимают активно используемые страницы индексов и таблиц, чтобы правильно сконфигурировать `innodb_buffer_pool_size`

Comment: Непонятно, в чем тут затруднение, 6гб база, 6500 мб память - крохотная база целиком в памяти. Или может это опечатка, и 6 ТБ?